# WebSphere application server network deployment version migration

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

I have  WebSphere  application server network deployment version 7 with below configurations

- One Deployment manager
- 2 nodes (each node in separate machines).
- Under each node  one server.
- And one cluster comprising of two  servers (one from each node).
- All configurations(data source,queues,etc) are done on Cluster scope
- One application is deployed and running on the cluster scope.

I need to install and migrate the above setup to WebSphere application server network deployment version 8.(preferably using migration scripts that comes with installation)

What are the steps to be followed and in what sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Version to version migration is an extensive topic.  I recommend starting with [Migration planning for WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008724).